# Shopify-api-node: Fetch published articles

Tags: node.js, sdk, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

in my Node project I am fetching articles from shopify app.
Code:

```
await shopify.article.list(blockId, { limit: 2 });
```

Now here I am getting both published/unpublished articles. I only want to fetch published articles.
Can you suggest me, which params I need to pass to fetch only published articles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can filter by asking for only published articles? It is an amazing thing.

```
published_status: "published"
```

So that ensures your GET articles just returns published articles. Amazing!

Comment: Thanks David, but it didn't work in my case. I need to do this `published_status: 'published'` and fixed the issue.
github ref: https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node/issues/537 
shopify ref: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/article#get-blogs-blog-id-articles

Answer (score 0):

Doing this solved my issue:

```
await shopify.article.list(blogId, {
  limit: 2,
  published_status: 'published'
});
```

github: https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node/issues/537 
shopify: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/article#get-blogs-blog-id-articles

Comment: True there. I made a typo. But you got the point. Read the docs, make filters. Bingo.